# can't enable "normal startup" on system configuration after clean boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

I had a problem regarding to freeze on windows7 log on screen in normal boot but there was no problem on safe mode.
So I performed clean boot and enabled all services and startup programs piecemeal. However 
the issue was solved itself and I didn't figure out what had caused the problem.

Now that I want to enable normal startup, after select "normal startup" and pressing apply the radio button switches to "selective startup " spontaneous. (it's the same about selecting check boxes for Kaspersky in services and startup tabs).

Now I don't have wifi connectivity, audio, display brightness and more.

Comment: I had malicious software knock out my audio, brightness, wifi, system restore and power options. I turned on the services one a at a time until my system restore worked. A system restore was the only thing which worked for me.

Comment: @Dave You Mean I Should Turn On My Services One By One In msconfig? My Last Restore Point Is For 8Month Ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it,
Downloaded Default Windows 7 Service Pack 1 Services Start Key registry file and applied it, everything got fixed. Download it here:  http://www.blackviper.com/2010/12/16/windows-7-service-pack-1-services-registry-files-2/